# Pass argument to annotation processor

Tags: java, maven, annotations

I'm using annotation processing for generation some classes... I have two modules, the processor itself and the "client" module using it. I'd like to pass an argument to the processor through the client, something I could like that

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</generatedSourcesDirectory>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>org.rapster.xxx.xxx.xxComponentProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                    <compilerArgs>
                       <arg>-Awidget=something</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And how to retrieve this argument on processor side?

Answer (score 6):

You can get this argument as follows -

```
processingEnvironment.getOptions().get("widget")
```

Please note that only arguments starting with '-A' will be available by this means.

Answer (score 2):

From within an implementation of `AbstractProcessor` you can retrieve the arguments using:

```
processingEnv.getOptions().get("widget");
```

Note that you need to declare the options supported by your processor, either by using the annotation `@SupportedOptions({"widget"})` or by overriding the method `public Set<String> getSupportedOptions()`.